# How to compose dynamic expression from string

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

Here's the sample code

```
string srJson = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(srJson);

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(srJson);

foreach (var builds in json.result)
{
    string fileName = builds.CommentId;
}
```

I am using Json.Net library. It uses dynamic expressions

**How can i compose this CommentId from string ?**

Currently i hard typed it but i want to be able to compose it from string so i can pull data from SQL server and get values i need.

C# .net 4.5 wpf

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject` supports `IDictionary<string, object>` interface. Instead of `builds.CommentId` you can use `builds["COmmentId"]`.

There're ways to [interact with dynamic types that don't implement dictionary interface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding), but they are complex and are not needed here to work with JSON.